# Is there a better/smaller way to compare the values of matrix

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have an array in matrix form

```
int[][] matrix=new int[3][3];


//comparing the numbers of row 1
if(matrix[0][0]==1 && matrix[0][1]==0 && matrix[0][2]==1){
System.out.println("Some Message");
}
```

This Works Fine but is there any smaller and faster approach than writing

```
if(matrix[0][0]==1 && matrix[0][1]==0 && matrix[0][2]==1)
```

to compare values because I have to do the same for row 2 and row 3 of the matrix

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop for this.

```
int[][] matrix=new int[3][3];
for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {
    boolean result = true;
    for(int j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++) {
        if(matrix[i][j] != (j+1)%2) {
            result = false;
            break;
        } 
    }
    if(result) {
        System.out.println("Some Message");
    }
}
```